# When to use goto instead of control structure nesting?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Valid use of goto for error management in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788903/valid-use-of-goto-for-error-management-in-c)
>   [Examples of good gotos in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245742/examples-of-good-gotos-in-c-or-c)
>   [GOTO still considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful)
>   [To Use GOTO or Not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379172/to-use-goto-or-not)

The goto statement seems very risky to use.  When would it be a good scenario to use a goto statement instead of nesting control statements?  Is it even a preferred way of controlling a program flow?

Comment: many dupes, including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788903/valid-use-of-goto-for-error-management-in-c

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GoTo is good just for error handling in VB6, when you program in assembler or for a Pic. In high level programming it's considered a bad practice because "breaks" the program control flow and also makes the code harder to read.