# Program to find the longest word in a string

Tags: c, string, loops

I wrote a program to find the longest word in a string and print the number of letters in the longest word. But the code is not printing. I analyzed the program many times but I could not find the solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char string[100] = "Hello Kurnool";
    int i = 0, letters = 0, longest = 0;

start:

    for (; string[i] !=' '; i++) {
        letters++;  
    }

    if (letters >= longest)
        longest = letters;

    if (string[i] == ' ') {
        letters = 0;
        i++;
        goto start;
    }

    printf("%d", longest);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve your code to get no warnings. [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). Be aware that  *stdout* is buffered (so use `fflush` or end every `printf` format string with `\n`...)

Comment: don't use goto.

Comment: printf() out the value of 'i' in the for loop.

Comment: You don't check for end of string change the test `for(;string[i]!=' ' && string[i]!=0;i++)`

Comment: Why should not I use goto

Comment: ..or put a breakpoint on 'letters++;' and inspect 'i'.

Comment: Why avoiding `goto`: Because Dijkstra [told us](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~storm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf) in 1968

Comment: Hey guys, have you heard that goto is considered harmful!? Lets debate it, surely that's not been done before.

Comment: why not goto? because enternal loop is much more clear, and this question probably never be set

Comment: Never use go to and similar things, that all can be handled by functions / recursions / loops, its more readable and easier to debug.. 
Except this- you can use [strtok()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9210560/4892907) to split String by delimiter, then you can have temp variable with the current longest word, and you can get length of each word by using [strlen](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String-Length.html).. So 1. split, 2. loop per number of elements/ words 3. compare to get the longest one

Comment: `goto` should only be used in cases where it does improve readability [What is wrong with using goto?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3517726/995714), [Use GOTO or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/379172/995714), [GOTO still considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46586/995714)

Comment: Avoid `goto` in code to avoid lengthy `goto` discussions in code review.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `goto` is highly discouraged. You should convert your code to use a loop.

The main problem in your code is you do not stop the scan when you reach the end of the string.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char string[100] = "Hello Kurnool";
    int i, letters, longest = 0, longest_pos = 0;

    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        for (letters = 0; string[i] != '\0' && string[i] != ' '; i++) {
            letters++;  
        }
        if (letters > longest) {
            longest = letters;
            longest_pos = i - longest;
        }
    }    
    printf("longest word: %d letters, '%.*s'\n",
           longest, longest, string + longest_pos);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the implementation can be simplified into a single loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char string[100] = "Hello Kurnool";
    int i, start = 0, longest = 0, longest_pos = 0;

    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (string[i] == ' ') {
            start = i + 1;
        } else {
            if (i - start > longest) {
                longest = i - start;
                longest_pos = start;
            }
        }
    }    
    printf("longest word: %d letters, '%.*s'\n",
           longest, longest, string + longest_pos);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have missed putting braces `{}` in `if (letters > longest)` block because of which the program may not give correct output for other cases. The statements `longest = letters;` and `longest_pos = i - longest;` should be within if block `{` and `}`.

Comment: Nice improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Below is my approach. You should use C's string manipulation functions. This is the correct way to deal with strings in C.

In the code below, first I acquire the required bytes to store the input string in heap. Then I use `strtok` to split the string into tokens based on a delemeter and get the length of each sub string. Finally I free the space that I have allocated with `malloc`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define phrase "Hello Kurnool"
int main()
{
    char* string = malloc(strlen(phrase)+1);
    strcpy(string,phrase);
    int longest=0;
    char *token;
    char delimeter[2] = " ";

   /* get the first token */
   token = strtok(string, delimeter);

   /* walk through other tokens */
    while( token != NULL ) {
        printf( " %s\n", token );
        if(longest < strlen(token)){
            longest = strlen(token);
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, delimeter);
   }
    printf("%d",longest);
    free(string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use of `strspn()` and `strcpsn()` can be used instead of `strtok()`, thus negating  the need for a `malloc()`, `strlen()` and `free()`.

Answer (score 1):

People say - `dont use goto` but there is nothing inherently wrong with `goto`. Only thing is if `goto` is not used judiciously, it makes code more difficult to understand and maintain. For example, the way you have used it in your program ( instead of `goto`, a loop is perfect fit in such cases). Check this:
[To use goto or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105746/to-use-goto-or-not)
[What is wrong with using goto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto)

Coming to your code, the `for` loop condition does not have check for terminating null character

```
for (; string[i] !=' '; i++) {
```

Hence it will not stop at the end of string.
To find the number of letters in longest word of string, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char string[100] = "Hello Kurnool";
    int i, letters = 0, longest = 0;

    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (string[i] != ' ') {
            letters++;
            if (letters > longest) {
                longest = letters;
            }
        } else {
            letters = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("longest : %d\n", longest);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,Please avoid using Goto, it is not a good practice.

Secondly, your loop will run infinite times when it iterates the second time because:

```
for(;string[i]!=' ';i++) // Here String[i] will never be equal to ' ' As there is no white space after your last word.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can never expect what might be going wrong with your program if you are using

> goto statement

which is never advisable to use rather it's bad programming if you use it. Secondly it looks like you are stuck in an infinite loop so her is a solution to your problem:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
    char s[1000];
    scanf("%s",s);
    int i=0;
    int letters;
    int longest=0;
    while(s[i]!=NULL)
   {
      if(s[i]==' ')
      {
         if(longest>=letters)
              {longest=letters;}
         letters=0;
       }
      else
         {letters++;}
    }
printf("%d\n",longest);
}
```

So, what I have done is assuming a string s which is the input given by the user. You itterate through s till the last input given by the user after which it encounters a NULL character. Now you are searching for the length of the longest word, so you create a variable **letters** for counting the no. of letters in each word of the string. And if the string s encounters a space indicating the end of a word, then you check if the variable **longest** is greater than or less than the word count. And again you initialize **letters** to 0, so that it can start counting the next word from 0 again.So, by this method at the end i.e. after the **while** loop terminates we get our required output which is stored in the variable **longest**.
So, I guess this will print the no. of letters in the longest word.