# How to loop back to the beginning of a switch statement after a case

Tags: c++, loops, switch-statement

I have what I'm sure is a simple problem, but I can't figure it out. In the code below, I'd like to be able to have case 5 re-display the options afterward. How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

```
// Input the race of your character
    cout << "Choose a race here: " << endl
    << "1) Human, 2) Elf, 3) Dark Dwarf, 4) Commoner, 5) Race info, 6) Admin Debug Race : ";

    cin >> mCharRace;

    switch (mCharRace)
        {
        case 1:
        cout << "You have chosen Human!" << endl;
        mExpPoints = 999;
        mArmor = mArmor + 2;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "You have chosen Elf!" << endl;
        mAccuracy = mAccuracy + 2;
        mWeapon.mDamageRange.mLow = mWeapon.mDamageRange.mLow + 1;
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "You have chosen Dark Dwarf!" << endl;
        mWeapon.mDamageRange.mHigh = mWeapon.mDamageRange.mHigh + 2;
        mMaxHitPoints = mMaxHitPoints + 3;
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << "You have chosen Commoner! Brave man." << endl;
        mAccuracy       = mAccuracy - 3;
        mHitPoints      = mHitPoints - 5;
        mMaxHitPoints   = 8;
        mExpPoints      = -250;
        mNextLevelExp   = 1500;
        mArmor          = -1;
        break;
    case 5:
        cout << "Placeholder for explanation text." << endl;
        break;
    case 6:
        cout << "ADMIN POWERS UNITE!!!!!!!" << endl;
        mAccuracy       = 20;
        mHitPoints      = 1000;
        mMaxHitPoints   = 1000;
        mExpPoints      = 0;
        mNextLevelExp   = 1000;
        mArmor          = 100;
        mWeapon.mName   = "Admin Sword of HNNNG!";
        mWeapon.mDamageRange.mLow   = 100;
        mWeapon.mDamageRange.mHigh  = 150;
        mGold           = 1000000;
        break;
```

Comment: Not an answer, 'cause I don't want to get hammered. There's always Duff's device: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**A switch-case construct isn't an iteration construct.** It can only select a certain case and execute it. The flow of control cannot go back up due to it.

So, you can't use it to loop.
Wrap it in a **while** or **for** looping construct instead.

```
while(condition){
   switch (mCharRace){
   ...
   ...
   }
}
```

Just turn **condition** to **false** when you want to stop looping.

Answer (score 6):

Wrap the input and switch code in a loop, and assign a variable `exitLoop` to exit the loop. Set that variable to TRUE by default, except in those cases where you want to repeat the input. In those, set `exitLoop` to false.

Answer (score 1):

Add a label before your first cout

```
label:

cout << "Choose a race here: " << endl
<< "1) Human, 2) Elf, 3) Dark Dwarf, 4) Commoner, 5) Race info, 6) Admin Debug Race : ";

cin >> mCharRace;
...
```

then inside the case 5, add

```
goto label;
```

Comment: Can I ask why this was downvoted? It works, and is simple. Is it just bad technique?

Comment: You will certainly love assembler, cjamesm :-) In all other cases, **please don't use a goto** (I didn't downvote)

Comment: `goto` should be avoided in general in C++. There are uses for it, but this one doesn't really fit.

Comment: May I ask why, Mat? I'm probably getting over my head here, but I'm curious because it seems so elegant.

Comment: @Mat goto is never neccessary and seldom useful. Please provide an example where adding a goto helps readability.

Comment: @Jan: that's an age-old debate I won't go into. I'll stick with exactly what I said: there are uses for it, but should be avoided in general.

Comment: Okay, anyone- why all the goto hate? Now I'm interested! :)

Comment: @Vladimir: some discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379172/to-use-goto-or-not

Comment: Thanks for the tips on goto, guys. I didn't know it existed until recently, now I guess I'll go on to forget about it..!

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside a `for(;;)` loop and use `continue` instead of `break`. Put another `break` after the end of the `switch` statement to catch the cases that really do want to break:

```
for (;;)
{
    switch (x)
    {
    case case_that_wants_to_loop:
        // ...
        continue;
    case case_that_wants_to_break:
        // ...
        break;
    }
    break;
}
```