# Pausing and resuming for loop c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop

I would like to know is there a way to to return back to the last iteration of the for loop, after the break and continue from there, for ex.:

```
void loop()
{
    for (n ; n<10; n++)
        if (n=5) { break; }
}

// code

loop();  // should start from 6 ...
```

Comment: loop here is a function which has a loop... If you want to keep state between function invocations you should use a static variable although it won't be thread safe:

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent C++ to Python generator pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059187/equivalent-c-to-python-generator-pattern)

Comment: Seems a strange construct:)  Anyway, if you want to do such stuff, use a while loop with an explicit counter, initialized before the loop.

Comment: Aside: `n==5`, not `n=5`.

Comment: Looks like an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

Write a class:

```
class my_loop
{
    int i;
public:
    my_loop(): i(0) {}
    void loop_some()
    {
        while (i != some_limit)
            ...
    }
};
```

The instance of the class contains the necessary info for running the loop. You can return from `loop_some()` and call it again when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `n` as a static variable, (`static int n=0`) so it  retains its value and use `continue` instead of `break`.

```
void loop()
 {
      static int n=0;
      for (; n<10; n++){

          if (n==5  ){  

             cout<<"  n = 5   "; 
             continue; 
          }

            cout<<""<<n<<" ";
       }

}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4   n = 5   6 7 8 9
 Press any key to continue
```

Answer (score -1):

What i could think of would be to use *goto* to to leave and go back into your loop. But you should try to avoid this because it leads to very difficult readable code. Here are two links which could help to decide:

[Use goto or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379172/to-use-goto-or-not?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

[Statements and flow control](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/)