# How to achieve some exclusive statements and some common statements for multiple cases in a switch?

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement, goto

I have a `switch` statement where each case has unique code, and some code that is shared between all cases except the default label.
Is there a good way to have a shared command between the different case labels?

Edit: code example

```
switch (c)
{
    case '+':
        command.type = ADD;
        commands.push_back(command);
        break;
    case '-':
        command.type = SUB;
        commands.push_back(command);
        break;
    case '>':
        command.type = INC;
        commands.push_back(command);
        break;
    case '<':
        command.type = DEC;
        commands.push_back(command);
        break;
    case '.':
        command.type = PUT;
        commands.push_back(command);
        break;
    case ',':
        command.type = GET;
        commands.push_back(command);
        break;
    default: break;
```

Comment: You might be able to refactor the code into functions.  Can you share an example of the code?

Comment: If it's shared for all cases, put it before (or after) the switch.

Comment: Switch cases have fall-through, if you mean to execute the same statements for every switch case.

Comment: Show your code!

Comment: Change the switch statement to something like this: `return_type func(container& cmd, const type option /* ADD, SUB, etc. */)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Set a flag to true
- in the default case of the switch, set the flag to false
- run the common code if the flag is true.

Something like the following:

```
bool MyPushBackFlag = true;
switch (c)
{
    case '+':
        command.type = ADD;
        break;
    case '-':
        command.type = SUB;
        break;
    case '>':
        command.type = INC;
        break;
    case '<':
        command.type = DEC;
        break;
    case '.':
        command.type = PUT;
        break;
    case ',':
        command.type = GET;
        break;
    default: MyPushBackFlag = false; break;
}

if (MyPushBackFlag)
     commands.push_back(command);
```

Comment: `if( flag == true )` I hate this :(

Comment: @Slava For us it is clear that `if(MyPushBackFlag)` would work, but for OP :(

Comment: @Slava you hating it does not mean that it is bad.

Comment: @KyleKhalaf unnecessary verbose code is bad, while `if( pointer != nullptr )` instead of `if( pointer )` could add readability, comparing to `true` inside `if` is useless. You may write `if ( ( flag == true ) == true )` too as well, why not add more comparison to `true`?

Comment: @Slava it is just your preference. The confusion for a programmer when seeing `if(flag == true)`, in any programming language, is neglect. My preference is that logic is better than hands on experience with the syntax. I will teach my kids logic before syntax. And OP (student) needed to learn some logic here

Comment: @KyleKhalaf even if confusion is neglect does not make that code any good, that verbosity does not add any value.

Comment: @Slava: For a variable with a name like "flag", I'd consider it a corner case. I like code to actually resemble the way I'd read it in my mind using English sentences. For example, I'd never say to myself *"if the pointer, then"* or *"if the vector's empty is true, then"*. I'd say *"if the pointer isn't null, then"* and *"if the vector is empty, then"*. That's why I prefer `if (pointer != nullptr`)` and `if (v.empty())`. Now, as far as "flag" is concerned, I *do* say to myself *"if the flag is true, then..."*, so I don't mind the `== true` here.

Comment: @Slava: Which brings me to the thought that the name itself is bad. The variable should be called `IsPushBackNecessary` (or something like that). That name would describe its intent, not its implementation as a boolean flag. And then, the `== true` would actually look bad, and `if (IsPushBackNecessary)` would be clearly better.

Answer (score 12):

Keep a `std::map` from `char` to whatever type `command.type` is.
Let's call it `command_table`.

Then:

```
switch (c)
{
    case '+':
    case '-':
    case '>':
    case '<':
    case '.':
    case ',':
        command.type = command_table[c];
        commands.push_back(command);
        break;
    default: break;
}
```

Or, shorter and with the added benefit that it's harder to forget a case:

```
auto it = command_table.find(c);
if (it != command_table.end())
{
    command.type = it.second;
    commands.push_back(command);
}
```

Comment: if you have a map then you do not need switch

Comment: *"Let's call it `commands`."* Or let's call it something that doesn't clash with the already defined vector named `commands`.

Comment: Definitely cleaner and shorter in this case

Answer (score 2):

sometimes refactoring the code just increases complexity... :)

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

enum CommandType {
    ADD, SUB, INC, DEC, PUT, GET
};

struct Command {
    CommandType type;
};

std::vector<Command> commands;

using mapping = std::pair<char, CommandType>;

template<class T, class Iter, class Func>
bool dispatch(T &&t, Iter first, Iter last, Func &&f) {
    auto i = std::find_if(first, last, [&t](auto &&pair) { return std::get<0>(pair) == t; });
    if (i == last) {
        return false;
    }
    f(std::get<1>(*i));
    return true;
}

template<class T, std::size_t N, class Func>
bool dispatch(char t, std::array<mapping, N> const &range, Func &&f) {
    return dispatch(t, range.begin(), range.end(), std::forward<Func>(f));
}

bool my_switch(char c) {

    return dispatch(c,
                    std::array<mapping, 6> {{
                                                    {'+', ADD},
                                                    {'-', SUB},
                                                    {'>', INC},
                                                    {'<', DEC},
                                                    {'.', PUT},
                                                    {',', GET}
                                            }}, [](auto type) {
                Command command{};
                command.type = type;
                commands.push_back(command);
                std::cout << "dispatched: " << command.type << std::endl;
            })
           or [](char c) { 
        std::cout << "invalid option " << c << std::endl;
        return false;
    }(c);
}


int main() {
    my_switch('+');
    my_switch('<');
    my_switch('U');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a switch statement where each case has unique code, and some code that is shared between all cases except the default label.

For your particular example case, where the only difference between different cases is in data, rather than execution, a map is probably more appropriate (see [molbdnilo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43545816/2079303)).

In general, where a map is not appropriate (i.e. when the code paths differ in their execution), you could use this primitive control structure, that is seldom used, `goto`:

```
switch( c )
{
    case '+': command.type = ADD; break;
    case '-': command.type = SUB; break;
    case '>': command.type = INC; break;
    case '<': command.type = DEC; break;
    case '.': command.type = PUT; break;
    case ',': command.type = GET; break;
    default:
        goto no_match; // or return from function if appropriate
}
commands.push_back( command );
no_match:
//...
```

This is clearer and easier to read than a flag variable - although that is just my opinion.

Comment: @ Whoever downvoted, how did you find the answer unhelpful? Do you have a suggestion to improve it?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the first thing I thought after having read your answer was this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/379259/1133284 .

Comment: Although the solution will work it's far from idiomatic and involves using a language feature that is below bottom on most peoples list. I'm just not seeing any value here.

Comment: Using `goto` in this case is simpler, cleaner and more efficient than the alternatives. But we rather jump through ridiculous hoops to avoid it because we are so afraid of it?

Answer (score 0):

We can have an effect of `goto` without actually using it.

```
#define GOTO_END(...) { __VA_ARGS__; } if(false)
#define END {}
switch(c)
{
  case '+': GOTO_END(command.type = ADD)
  case '-': GOTO_END(command.type = SUB) // if `c == '-'` then jump to END
  case '>': GOTO_END(command.type = INC)
  case '<': GOTO_END(command.type = DEC)
  case '.': GOTO_END(command.type = PUT)
  case ',': GOTO_END(command.type = GET)
            END // <--- must not be forgotten
            commands.push_back(command);
  default:  break;        
}
```