# C: Nested Ifs or Gotos

Tags: c, if-statement, goto

What is the best way to manage resources for a **C** program. Should I use a nested if structure or should I use goto statements?

I am aware there is a lot of **taboo** about **goto** statements. However, I think it is justified for local resource clean up. I have supplied two samples. One compares a nested if structure and another uses goto statements. I personally find the goto statements make the code easier to read. For those who might argue that the **nested if** prompt better structure, imagine if the datatype was something other than a char*, like a Windows handle. I feel that the **nested if** structure would get out of hand with a series of **[CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx)** functions or any other function that takes large quantities of parameters.

This [article](http://vilimpoc.org/research/raii-in-c/) demonstrates that local goto statements create RAII for C code. The code is neat an easy to follow. Imagine that as a series of **nested if** statements.

I understand that **goto** is taboo in many other languages because their exists other control mechanisms like try/catch etc, however, in C it seems appropriate.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STRING_MAX 10

void gotoExample()
{
    char *string1, *string2, *string3, *string4, *string5;

    if ( !(string1 = (char*) calloc(STRING_MAX, sizeof(char))) )
        goto gotoExample_string1;
    if ( !(string2 = (char*) calloc(STRING_MAX, sizeof(char))) )
        goto gotoExample_string2;
    if ( !(string3 = (char*) calloc(STRING_MAX, sizeof(char))) )
        goto gotoExample_string3;
    if ( !(string4 = (char*) calloc(STRING_MAX, sizeof(char))) )
        goto gotoExample_string4;
    if ( !(string5 = (char*) calloc(STRING_MAX, sizeof(char))) )
        goto gotoExample_string5;

    //important code goes here

gotoExample_string5:
    free(string4);
gotoExample_string4:
    free(string3);
gotoExample_string3:
    free(string2);
gotoExample_string2:
    free(string1);
gotoExample_string1:
}

void nestedIfExample()
{
    char *string1, *string2, *string3, *string4, *string5;

    if (string1 = (char*) calloc(STRING_MAX, sizeof(char))) 
    {
        if (string2 = (char*) calloc(STRING_MAX, sizeof(char)))
        {
            if (string3 = (char*) calloc(STRING_MAX, sizeof(char)))
            {
                if (string4 = (char*) calloc(STRING_MAX, sizeof(char)))
                {
                    if (string5 = (char*) calloc(STRING_MAX, sizeof(char)))
                    {
                        //important code here
                        free(string5);
                    }
                    free(string4);
                }
                free(string3);
            }
            free(string2);
        }
        free(string1);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    nestedIfExample();
    gotoExample();
    return 0;
}
```

I would also like to quote Linus Torvalds on **goto** statements inside the Linux [Kernel](http://kerneltrap.org/node/553/2131).

> And sometimes structure is *bad*, and
>   gets into the way, and using a  "goto"
>   is just much clearer.
>
> For example, it is quite common to
>   have conditionals THAT DO NOT NEST.
>
> In which case you have two
>   possibilities
>
> - use goto, and be happy, since it doesn't enforce nesting
>
>   This makes the code *more* readable,
>     since the code just does what     the
>     algorithm says it should do.
> - duplicate the code, and rewrite it in a nesting form so that you can
>     use the structured jumps.
>
>   This often makes the code much LESS
>     readable, harder to maintain,     and
>     bigger.
>
> The Pascal language is a prime example
>   of the latter problem. Because it 
>   doesn't have a "break" statement,
>   loops in (traditional) Pascal end up 
>   often looking like total shit, because
>   you have to add totally arbitrary 
>   logic to say "I'm done now".

Is **goto** acceptable for resource management? Should I use **nested if** statements or is there a better way?

**Update:** [Examples of Good Gotos In C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245742/examples-of-good-gotos-in-c-or-c)

Comment: note that your goto's goto the wrong place -- if your malloc for string1 fails, you don't want to free the memory you couldn't allocate :)

Comment: @KevinDTimm: A failed allocation is signaled by a null pointer -- and passing a null pointer to `free` is harmless (a nop). In this case, assuring you `free` only the successful allocations leads to (considerable) extra work.

Comment: @Jerry - while that is true, it's a tough paradigm for many to grok.  The freeing of a null pointer can be a task switch and so I try not to do it (therefore, only freeing successful allocations)

Comment: @KevinDTimm: Where in the world do you get the idea that freeing a null pointer would have anything to do with task switches?

Comment: @Jerry - task switch - the thing your brain does when it doesn't grok something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cleanup using `goto` has the advantage that it's less error-prone. Having to free each and every resource allocated on each and every return point can lead to someone someday missing some cleanup when doing maintenance work.

That said, I'll quote Knuth's "Structured Programming with goto Statements":

> I argue for the elimination of go to's in certain cases, and for their introduction in others.

and Knuth's quote of Dijkstra in that same paper:

> "Please don't fall into the trap of believing that I am terribly dogmatical about [the go to statement]. I have the uncomfortable feeling that others are making a religion out of it, as if the conceptual problems of programming could be solved by a single trick, by a simple form of coding discipline!" [29].

Answer (score 11):

If by using `goto` you can avoid writing complex code, then use `goto`.

Your example could also be written like this (no `goto`s):

```
void anotherExample()
{
    char *string1, *string2, *string3, *string4, *string5;
    string1 = string2 = string3 = string4 = string5 = 0;
    if ((string1 = (char*) calloc(STRING_MAX, sizeof(char)))
     && (string2 = (char*) calloc(STRING_MAX, sizeof(char)))
     && (string3 = (char*) calloc(STRING_MAX, sizeof(char)))
     && (string4 = (char*) calloc(STRING_MAX, sizeof(char)))
     && (string5 = (char*) calloc(STRING_MAX, sizeof(char))))
    {
       //important code here
    }

  free(string1);
  free(string2);
  free(string3);
  free(string4);
  free(string5);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

No doubt about it Dijkstra was a formidable personality in the programming world. His
[Goto Considered Harmful](http://www.massey.ac.nz/~kahawick/159331/Goto-Harmful-Dijkstra.pdf) paper
was way overblown. Yes GoTo may be used indiscriminately and can be harmfull but many think an outright ban on GoTo is
not warranted. Knuth provided a very well reasoned rebuttal to Dijkstra in: 
[Structured Programming with GO TOs](http://pplab.snu.ac.kr/courses/adv_pl05/papers/p261-knuth.pdf)

Read Knuth's paper, you will find that your GoTo pattern is one of the good uses
for GoTo.

BTW, Dijkstra is very quotable for a number of other things too. How about:

- Object-oriented programming is an exceptionally bad idea which could only have originated in California.

Dijkstra was a great mathematician and made huge contributions to computer science. However, I don't
think he had to deal with, or was interested in, the day to day type stuff that 99.99 percent of
our programs do.

Use GoTo only with reason and structure. Use them rarely. But do use them.

Answer (score 6):

#### Always use one goto in each program to annoy the purists

---

That's my philosophy.

Seriously, on some occasions a `goto` is reasonable, especially if it just does something obvious like jump to common return code at the bottom of a function.

Comment: Resource cleanup _is_ the canonical example of using goto in C.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I have used goto in this manner in the past.  People hate it because it reminds them of the spaghetti code they used to write/maintain, or because someone who wrote/maintaned such code beat the concept that gotos are evil into them.

You probably could write something decent without goto, sure.  But it's not going to do any harm in this kind of circumstance.

Comment: Agreed. I use it, but still hate it cause it reminds me how annoying coding in C is (when compared to C++).

Comment: Hah, sorry, you're talking to the wrong guy if you prefer C++ over C. ;)

Comment: Oh, well, not everyone can make it to the next level :-P

Comment: The next level, that would be java :O

Comment: Yeah, a language without any sort of function pointer concept, where every method is virtual, and you cannot have different implementations for two interface members with the same signature.  Next level. *cough* Yeah.

Comment: C'mon - somebody had to say it (and yes, I miss all those things, but there are payoffs)

Comment: @Kevin Well, that is why I don't like java at all. It gives you some improvements, but far far less then most other higher level languages, but you still pay with a pretty big performance hit and huge semantic restrictions.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be - but, everybody's doing it, shouldn't we too?  ;)

Comment: @Kevin Well, companies that don't want to pay for good programmers, or their further education use it. It's a good coding monkey languages (best language for this usage IMHO).

Comment: @LetMB - seems harsh, I use many languages (OK, java/C/python/objc) and find each of them to have their place.  10 years of java/25 years of C and just year of python and objc).  I'm not exactly a monkey coder - though I'm not K or R, or Bjarne, or Gosling, or .....

Answer (score 2):

From two of your alternatives, goto is naturally better and nicer. But there's a third and better alternative: Use recursion!

Comment: Recursion is elegant but I do not see how its possible when there is a resource dependency.

Comment: @Shiftbit: the resource can either be global, or can be passed as a pointer parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I'd structure the code differently than either one. Unless I had some outstanding reason to do otherwise, I'd probably write the code something like this:

```
char *strings[5] = {NULL};

int all_good = 1;

for (i=0; i<5 && all_good; i++) {
    strings[i] = malloc(STRING_MAX);
    all_good &= strings[i] != NULL;
}

if (all_good)
    important_code();

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    free(strings[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

One very big difference between the example in the article you link to and the code you're posting is that your gotos labels are `<functionName>_<number>` and their goto labels are `cleanup_<thing_to_cleanup>`.

You're be using `goto line_1324` next, and the code will get edited so the `line_1234` label  is on line 47823 ...

Use it like the example, and be very careful to write code to be read.

Comment: Using cleanup_<thing_to_cleanup> could cause a collisions. By prefixing it with the function name I am ensuing each label will be unique. Perhaps you would prefer a double prefix <functionName>_cleanup_<thing_to_cleanup>?

Comment: to clarify I am using <functionName>_<thing_to_cleanup> not <functionName>_<number>

Comment: @Shiftbit Don't know what you're programming in, but in C99 § 6.2.1 "A label name is the only kind of identifier that has function scope."

Comment: Interesting. I will observe clean_up<thing_to_cleanup> in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what you're doing, and the resulting code looks cleaner and more readable (I bet it does), then there's absolutely no problem with using goto's. Especially the 'graceful initialization failure recovery' example you showed is widely used.

BTW, when writing structured code that initializes 100 things, you'd need 100 levels of indentation...which is plain ugly.

Comment: "100 things, you'd need 100 levels of indentation...which is plain ugly." - Exactly

Comment: If you're writing structured code that initialises 100 things, then you use a for loop. Something has already gone wrong in your design if you need to initialise 100 different things in the same function.

Comment: I agree 100 things is a little absurd. However, it is not always possible to create a loop for things such as file handles which require specific attributes. Even if it was nested 7 or 8 times it would still be awkward to read.

Answer (score 1):

In C, `goto` is often the only way to approximate cleanup code like C++ destructors or Java `finally` clauses.  Since it's really the best tool you have for that purpose, I say use it.  Yeah, it's easy to abuse, but so are a lot of programming constructs.  For example, most Java programmers wouldn't hesitate to throw exceptions, but exceptions are also easy to abuse if they're used for something other than error reporting, such as flow control.  But if you're using `goto` explicitly for the purpose of avoiding cleanup-code duplication, then it's safe to say you're probably not abusing it.

You can find many perfectly reasonable uses of `goto` in the Linux kernel, for example.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I prefer this style of goto error handling.  Taking Nick D's snippet one step further, it uses one general goto label for error handling.

```
void gotoExample()
{
    char *string1, *string2, *string3, *string4, *string5;
    string1 = string2 = string3 = string4 = string5 = NULL;

    if ( !(string1 = (char*) calloc(STRING_MAX, sizeof(char))) )
        goto HANDLE_ERROR;
    if ( !(string2 = (char*) calloc(STRING_MAX, sizeof(char))) )
        goto HANDLE_ERROR;
    if ( !(string3 = (char*) calloc(STRING_MAX, sizeof(char))) )
        goto HANDLE_ERROR;
    if ( !(string4 = (char*) calloc(STRING_MAX, sizeof(char))) )
        goto HANDLE_ERROR;
    if ( !(string5 = (char*) calloc(STRING_MAX, sizeof(char))) )
        goto HANDLE_ERROR;

    //important code goes here


HANDLE_ERROR:
  if (string5)
    free(string5);

  if (string4)
    free(string4);

  if (string3)
    free(string3);

  if (string2)
    free(string2);

  if (string1)
    free(string1);

}
```