# C program that prints out the non repeated number in an array using break statement

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, if-statement, break

so I was searching about a program that prints out the non repeated numbers in an array, the program is completely fine but I can't understand what exactly happens in the break statement part so can someone please explains what happens because I can't get it, here is the code down below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){

int n;
printf("enter a value for n: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
int T[n];
int j;  
printf("fill in the array: \n");
for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
{
    printf("enter value %d: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&T[i]);
}   
for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
{
    printf("%d ",T[i]);
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------------//

        
printf("the non repeated elements are: \n");
for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
{
    for( j=0 ; j<n ; j++)
    {
        if(T[i]==T[j] && i!=j)
        {
            break;
        }
            
            
    }
    if(j==n)
    {       
    printf("%d ",T[i]);         
    }
}   
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use break, and continue in C language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40080092/when-to-use-break-and-continue-in-c-language)

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop `for( j=0 ; j<n ; j++)` goes over all elements of the array (except the `i`th element), and check if they contain the same value as that of the `i`th element. If it does, it stops the loop **before** `j` gets to `n` (`break` means: stop the loop immediately). I.e. if `j == n` after the loop, it means that no such element was found (no `j != i` such that `T[i] == T[j]`), hence we print it.

The inner loop could have been written as follows and it would have been equivalent:

```
for( j = 0 ; j < n && (T[i] != T[j] || i == j) ; j++)
{
    // empty
}
```

And the outer loop `for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)` does this for every element (every index `i`) in the array `T`.