# Breaking if statement PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, break

I need to *break an if statement* somehow. Here is the code

```
public function userData($data) {
    //checks if user is in the database
    if (self::checkUserExist($data)==false) { 
        $userInfo = array();
        $userInfo['id'] = (isset($data->id)) ? $data->id : break;
        $userInfo['email'] = (isset($data->email)) ? $data->email : break;
        $this->conn->insert($userInfo, $Table); // inserts data!
    }
}
```

The break doesn't work here. I need to return some kind of error. I could say that the input data is invalid or something, the main point for this is to avoid data insertion in database if the data is invalid.

Comment: What you need to do is to [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) from the function

Comment: I wouldn't recomment to `break` or `return` in this case anyway ... the `if()` statement is the right place to insert dependencies (that's what it's there for).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
public function userData($data) {
     if (self::checkUserExist($data)==false && isset($data->id) && isset($data->email)) { //checks if user is in the database
            $userInfo = array('id' => $data->id,'email' => $data->email);
            $this->conn->insert($userInfo, $Table); // inserts data!
     }
}
```

Or `return` or to make it even worse: `goto`.

Answer (score 1):

break breaks while/for loops. use return false

Answer (score 0):

You cannot break the `if`; If that is your whole code, you may use the `return` statement; Also, you should not combine it with a `ternary operator` (`? :`') as that will cause a parse error:

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'break' (T_BREAK)`
`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected return (T_RETURN)`

Another approach, would be to use [goto](https://www.php.net/goto) (I can hear the bashing coming, but take a look at this question: [Examples of good gotos in c or c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245742/examples-of-good-gotos-in-c-or-c))

Also there are obscure hacks like
`do { ... } while(0);`

that allows you to use `break`, but don't use that - this is stupid :)

Answer (score -1):

Try below code:

```
public function userData($data) {
     if (self::checkUserExist($data)==false) { //checks if user is in the database
            $userInfo = array();
        $userInfo['id'] = (isset($data->id)) ? $data->id : break;
            $userInfo['email'] = (isset($data->email)) ? $data->email : break;
            if(!$this->conn->insert($userInfo, $Table)){
              $message = 'Error';
            }else{
                $message = 'Success';
            }
     }
   }
```