# Partial reads for reads in nonblocking mode

Tags: c, linux

On page 34 of the book "Linux System Programming" the following example of correctly handling partial reads with a while loop for blocking reads is given

```
ssize_t ret;

while (len != 0 && (ret = read(fd, buf, len)) != 0) {
    if (ret == -1) {
        if (errno == EINTR) 
            continue;
        perror("read");
        break;
    }

    len -= ret;
    buf += ret;
}
```

On the next page it gives the following example for nonblocking reads. Does this example need to be wrapped in a while loop to handle the possibility of partial reads?

```
char buf[BUFSIZ];
ssize_t nr;

start:
nr = read(fd, buf, BUFSIZ);
if (nr == -1) {
    if (errno == EINTR)
        goto start; /* oh shush */
    if (erron == EAGAIN)
        /* resubmit later */
    else
        /* error */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, a non-blocking IO is used when the code can (or intends to) do something else in parallel instead of waiting on input (e.g. check on another file or socket). Otherwise, a simple blocking IO will do the same trick as polling on the file for reads, as Jlghtuse mentioned. However, I am not sure if a non-blocking IO is guaranteed to return exact number of bytes requested. As a safe bet, it probably could use a while loop anyways. I think one usable code chunk might look like:

```
char buf[BUFSIZ];
ssize_t nr;
char *bufp = buf;
ssize_t rdbyts = 0;

while(rdbyts < BUFSIZ) {
    nr = read(fd, bufp, (BUFSIZ - rdbyts));
    if (nr == -1) {
        if (errno == EINTR)
            continue; /* oh shush */
        else if (errno == EAGAIN)
            /* resubmit later - might be do
             * something else and come back
             * or just sleep. */
            do_some_work_or_sleep();
            continue;
        else
            /* error */
            break;
    } else if (nr < (BUFSIZ - rdbytes)) {
        bufp += nr;
        rdbyts += nr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this example don't need to be wrapped in loop. It uses `goto` statement (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245742/examples-of-good-gotos-in-c-or-c) for good examples of its using).

This example shows nonblocking read, that's why this code differs from the first one. See note after second code block:

> Handling the EAGAIN case like we did the EINTR case (with a goto
>   start) would make little sense. We might as well not have used non‐
>   blocking I/O. The point of nonblocking I/O is to catch the EAGAIN and
>   do other, useful work.

Comment: But why isn't it possible for the nonblocking read to return something less than BUFSIZ indicating that only partial read occurred. In such a case `nr` would not be `-1` so that the error handling code is not relevant.