# How to use the "write" system call using C langauge in Linux?

Tags: c, linux

My code is working fine. The only error I'm getting is that after the program writes the text into the file i.e. text1.txt, the text file prints some weird symbols like /00 when I actually open it.

```
int fd;
fd = open("text1.txt", O_RDWR);
char text[] = "This is my file.";
write(fd,text,sizeof(text));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You need to ensure that `open` succeeded instead of blindly writing to the file-descriptor.

  - **Always check the return value of a syscall** (and most C standard library functions) and check `errno` if the return value indicated an error.
- [Your string literal will include a hidden `\0` (`NULL`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) character after the dot.

  - Writing `text` directly to the file will therefore include the trailing `\0` which is what you're seeing.

These issues can be rectified by:

- Always checking the return value of a syscall - and in this case: print a helpful error message to stdout and perform any necessary cleanup (the `goto closeFile;` statement).

  - Because C doesn't have a native `try/catch` or RAII it means its difficult to write terse error-handling and cleanup code, but using `goto` for common clean-up code [is generally acceptable in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245742/examples-of-good-gotos-in-c-or-c), hence the `goto closeFile` statement.
- Using `strlen` to get the actual length of the string.

  - Though in a pinch it's okay to use `sizeof(text) - 1` provided you're in a scope where the C compiler knows the length of `text` as using `sizeof()` won't work if you cross a function boundary [due to array pointer decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying).

Like so:

```
void writeToFile() {

    int fd = open( "text1.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY ); // Use `O_WRONLY` instead of `O_RDWR` if you're only writing to the file. Use `O_CREAT` to create a file if it doesn't already exist.
    if( fd == -1 ) {
        printf( "Error opening file: errno: %d - %s\n", errno, strerror( errno ) );
        return;
    }

    size_t textLength = strlen( text );
    size_t written = write( fd, text, textLength );
    if( written == -1 ) {
        printf( "Error writing text: errno: %d - %s\n", errno, strerror( errno ) );
        goto closeFile;
    }
    else if( written < textLength ) {
        printf( "Warning: Only %d of %d bytes were written.", written, textLength );
        goto closeFile;
    }
    else {
        // Carry on as normal.
    } 

closeFile:
    if( close( fd ) == -1 ) {
        printf( "Error closing file: errno: %d - %s\n", errno, strerror( errno ) );
    }
}
```