# Java is using 100% of CPU using sockets

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat

I have a Java application running on a tomcat that is in a Linux machine. This application works like a socket server, where about 15 devices are connected. Its seems like when a device sends a big message the cpu grows up until 100% usage. Te problem is that if I undeploy the application, java is still having 99% of the CPU. The application has two parts:

Socket server:

```
    public void iniciarSocket() {

    Runnable serverTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);

                System.out.println("Waiting a connection");

                while (true) {
                    Socket socket = null;

                    try {
                        socket = serverSocket.accept();

                        System.out.println("Client connected");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    new SocketThread(socket).start();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(serverTask);
    serverThread.start();
}
```

Each socket thread, which connect with each device:

```
    public void run() {
    try {

        //Output channel
        DataOutputStream salida;
        salida = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        System.out.println("Client connected.... ");

        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int bytesLeidos = 0;
        socket.setSoTimeout(300000);
        System.out.println("Timeout: " + socket.getSoTimeout());

        while((bytesLeidos = socket.getInputStream().read(buff, 0, buff.length)) > -1) {

            System.out.println("Bytes leidos: " + bytesLeidos);

            if ((bytesLeidos == 70) && (Protocolo.isStatusMessage(buff))) {
                Protocolo.decode(buff, salida);
            } else {

                int offset = 0;

                while (offset < bytesLeidos) {

                    while ((offset + 70 <= bytesLeidos) &&(!Protocolo.isStatusMessageWithOffset(buff, offset))) {
                        offset++;
                    }

                    if ((offset + 70 <= bytesLeidos) &&(Protocolo.isStatusMessageWithOffset(buff, offset))) {
                        Protocolo.decodeWithOffset(buff, offset, salida);
                        offset += 70;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println();
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Communication ended");
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Socket not closed");
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand what is happening and I'm traying a lot of things but I can't to solve the problem.

Comment: You're probably getting stuck in the `while (offset < bytesLeidos)` loop, in a case where you don't increment `offset.`

Comment: `while (true) {` ?, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580419/how-can-i-stop-a-java-while-loop-from-eating-50-of-my-cpu, in such cases also think about adding more logs.

Comment: SocketThread can be passed a null if your ServerSocket.accept() call fails.  Also, more generally, you should only catch the kinds of exception you're expecting such as SocketException instead of catching Exception.

Comment: "while (true) {" Your "serverThread"s will never die!

Comment: Yes, serverThread never die. It's necessary because the server is always waiting a new device. But it's not a busy waiting. This thread only stop if I deploy the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the problem is solved. EJP was right, if message is not multiple of 70 the loop never ends. I only had to change socketThread.

```
            while((bytesLeidos = socket.getInputStream().read(buff, 0, buff.length)) > -1) {

            System.out.println("Bytes leidos: " + bytesLeidos);

            if ((bytesLeidos == 70) && (Protocolo.isStatusMessage(buff))) {
                Protocolo.decode(buff, salida);
            } else {


                int offset = 0;

                // Code changed
                while (offset < bytesLeidos) {

                    if (Protocolo.isStatusMessageWithOffset(buff, offset)) {
                        // decodificar
                        Protocolo.decodeWithOffset(buff, offset, salida);
                        offset += 70;
                    } else {
                        offset++;
                    }
                }
                // End code changed
            }
        }
```

Thank you very much.