# Why does my Java drawing code take so much CPU?

Tags: java

I learned Java for 3 days and made a code to draw a diagonal line made from X. It's taking 28% of my i5 CPU and I don't know why.

```
public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        for (int i=0; i<20000; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            System.out.println("X");
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:** By the way, the output is kinda different between the first minutes I ran it and 10 minutes later. Weird. The distance between X get longer.
Screenshot in 10 minutes later

**Edit 2:** I made another code just to know the "progress" where i has reached, when i reaches 100, 200, etc. it'll print that. But the code failed to compile on Windows, it compiles fine on https://www.compilejava.net. What's the problem?

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) { 

for (int i=0; i<20000; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
    {
    System.out.print("  ");
    }
System.out.println("X");
if ((i % 100)==0) {
System.out.println("Your cute code made it to the 100th lapse!");
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Take a close look at your nested loops. Do you really want to print 20,000 X's?

Comment: @Zephyr What makes you think the loop has exponential increase? For me, it's linear.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580419/how-can-i-stop-a-java-while-loop-from-eating-50-of-my-cpu

Comment: @Glains the number of spaces in each line is twice `i`, so it will be quadratic

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is quite obvious that it will take a lot! 
it will iterate a lot of times! every value of j will be the summation of 20000 (1+2+3+4+...+19999+20000).

So the complexity is higher than `O(n)`.

Taking that into account, the number of prints you are doing is REALLY high. 20000 times X and summation of 20000 a white space!

Answer (score 1):

Your code attempts to print **20000** 'X' characters, as was observed in comments, but much worse, it attempts to print a total of about **400000000** space characters.  Computers are fast, but that will still take some effort.

Comment: @Gox, the result is exactly 400020000, or about 400000000, ***space characters***, exactly as I already corrected this answer to say, since each iteration of the inner loop prints two.

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate what is happening here, consider the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int iTotal = 0;
    int jTotal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            jTotal += 1;
        }
        iTotal += 1;
    }

    System.out.println("Total I: " + iTotal);
    System.out.println("Total J: " + jTotal);
    System.out.println("Total:   " + jTotal + iTotal);
}
```

Here I've removed the printing and just used counters to help you see exactly what is happening here

The output:

```
Total I: 20,000
Total J: 199,990,000
Total:   19,999,000,020,000
```

Comment: Why did John Bollinger calculate it to be 800000000 space characters, then?

Comment: @Basafish - I wasn't there when he did his calculation so I can't answer that ;)

Comment: Two reasons, @Basafish: (1) I counted the number of *space characters printed*, and each iteration of the inner loop prints a two-space string, and (2) I miscalculated by a factor of 2 (now corrected).

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger and Zephyr a lot for your efforts. 

Edit 2: I made another code just to know the "progress" where i has reached, when i reaches 100, 200, etc. it'll print that. But the code failed to compile on Windows, it compiles fine on https://www.compilejava.net. What's the problem?

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) { 

for (int i=0; i<20000; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
    {
    System.out.print("  ");
    }
System.out.println("X");
if ((i % 100)==0) {
System.out.println("Your cute code made it to the 100th lapse!");
}
}
}
}

Comment: @Basafish - If you have another question, please post it as a new question (**after** searching and trying to solve yourself, of course) :)

Comment: Zephyr, I'm afriad of asking another question because I'm scared that It'd get downvoted like this one :( It worked after I changed it into the code that users reformatted for me on StackOverflow though. Great community!

Comment: @Basafish - You can help avoid downvotes by reading the [ask] article and doing what it says :) Honestly, there's some great advice in there.

Answer (score 0):

You're executing about 200 million print calls, if my high-school math is correctly remembered. You're producing 20 thousand lines of screen output. It doesn't seem surprising that uses a reasonably significant amount of CPU and takes some time to complete.