# Python - I need a continuous loop that will run forever, I know its bad practice but would using while True be appropriate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, iteration

Would there be any better alternatives to creating a permanent loop (which are not while True) or I'm curious to know if using while True would be fine :) I'm just trying to poll something indefinitely and want to do it all with good coding practice :)
Thank you for your time!!

Have just tried while True (which works fine but wondering if theres a better alternative as it doesn't feel right to rely on it)

Comment: It's about as good as the concept of infinite loop itself. Which is not very good. But if you really need it, that's the most reasonable way.

Comment: @matszwecja great point! hahaha

Comment: Even in infinite polling, you might want to allow the user to exit your polling without killing your program directly, so you could have something like `while running:`, but if that makes sense depends on your specific case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little experiment, looking at the bytecode:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('while True: statement')
  1     >>    0 LOAD_NAME                0 (statement)
              2 POP_TOP
              4 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            0 (to 0)
```

Doesn't even bother checking whether `True` is true. Just does an unconditional loop. So even the Python compiler recognizes this as something special and treats it as the most optimal thing.

For comparison, using `1 == 1` suggested elsewhere:

```
>>> dis.dis('while 1 == 1: statement')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              4 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       12 (to 24)
        >>    8 LOAD_NAME                0 (statement)
             10 POP_TOP
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
             14 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
             16 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             18 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE         4 (to 8)
             20 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   24 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
```

Look at all that stuff. Loading the values, comparing them, then testing the comparison result's truth value and jumping around conditionally.

All that said, `True` isn't the only value optimal in this regard:

```
>>> dis.dis('while 42: statement')
  1     >>    0 LOAD_NAME                0 (statement)
              2 POP_TOP
              4 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            0 (to 0)
>>> dis.dis('while "foo": statement')
  1     >>    0 LOAD_NAME                0 (statement)
              2 POP_TOP
              4 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            0 (to 0)
>>>
```

But I'd say it's additionally the *clearest*.

Answer (score 1):

The usual and "Pythonic" way to create an infinite loop (assuming you really want one) is indeed `while True:`. Of course you shouldn't forget to have a `break` somewhere (that has an actual chance of getting executed).

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    do_something()
```

That is the best solution.
Alternatively, you can try:

```
while 1 == 1: #(or "a" == "a", you get it)
    do_something()
```

Comment: Ah so its as I expected, no better solution than this  thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, you can try `while 10/5*1410/11 > 132 > 99:`. But... why would you?

Comment: @matszwecja To flex, what else?

Comment: @KellyBundy Well, it works. And if it works, do not fix it: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_it_ain%27t_broke,_don%27t_fix_it

Answer (score 0):

### For Menu selections

If you need a continuous loop (infinite loop)  for menu selections (with something like a 'Quit' option), an ordinary `while` loop will do.

The priority is to avoid an *infinite loop runaway*. Of this, `while not choice == 'q'` serves as the first checkpoint and `case _`/`sys.exit(0)` for a safeguard breaker in the following sample.

```
import sys  # Optional for the 'Safeguard'

choice = 'any string you like'  # Initializer
while not choice == 'q':  # Substitute for a while-True-break loop.

    choice = input('Choose 1-3. Q for Quit >> ').lower()
    match choice:
        case '1':
            print('Spam')
        case '2':
            print('Spam and Spam')
        case '3':
            print('Spam and Spam with Spam')
        case _:
            print('Ni!')
            sys.exit(0)  # Safeguard: Optional for unexpected inputs.
```

### About the while-true loop

As Python doesn't have the `do{}while()` loop semantics, we sometimes use the `while True`/`break` loop. In this regard, I found the following discussion very helpful :)

Stack Overflow: [Is while (true) with break bad programming practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/390481/11042987)