# When to use while true

Tags: python

What are some acceptable use cases for using while true. I’ve heard that it’s not good practice to use while true and break. For simple use cases like let’s say a rps game, would it be worth using. If not, I’m considering to use boiler plate code.

Comment: "acceptable use cases" is a highly subjective topic. The best way I've seen it described is this: If you have a stopping criteria in mind, then put it in the loop definition/criteria. If the code is meant to run forever without stopping, then use `while True` as it's optimized for truly infinite loops (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71689682/python-i-need-a-continuous-loop-that-will-run-forever-i-know-its-bad-practice) for some efficiency comparisons)

Comment: You've heard that it is not good pratice, I have heard and seen otherwise. Check "[Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)" for example. The accepted answer (at the monment about 1000 upvotes) relies on `while True:`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `while(True)` in such conditions when you need to make the code running until interrupted by the person running the code.

A use case can be fee submitting system. The program needs to be running for the entire day. There are a lot of other use cases too.